# Periodically tiling a function

Tags: function-construction, periodic-function

I have a function which creates a hole of varying radius, depth and would like to tile it in x and y.

```
    Hole[x_, y_, radius_, holefraction_] := 
 Which[x^2 + y^2 <= radius, holefraction, x^2 + y^2 > radius, 1]
```

I have been playing around with the mod[] function, but can't seem to find the right way to rigidly offset the hole by an arbitrary pitch in x and y.  If this were in a loop, i would just iterate as x=xrelative+i*pitch, but how would I do the reverse, where I just want to rigidly pattern in x and y?
Alternatively, is there a way to create a 2nd function using this one, and just set periodic boundary conditions in x and y?  Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
PeriodicHole[p : {x_, y_}, radius_, holefraction_, per : {xPer_, yPer_}] :=
                       If[Norm[p - Round[p, per]] < radius, holefraction, 1]

Plot3D[PeriodicHole[{x, y}, .2, .1, {.5, .4}], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, 
 PlotPoints -> 50, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[Orange, Specularity[White, 20]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: `Round[ ]` threads automatically over lists

Answer (score 3):

You can generate the conditions that should go inside `Which` on the fly.

```
holes[x_, y_, radius_, holefraction_] := Which @@ Flatten[{
     Table[
      {Norm[{xp - x, yp - y}] <= radius, holefraction},
      {xp, 0, 10},
      {yp, 0, 10}
      ],
     True, 1
     }];
```

Test:

```
DensityPlot[
 holes[x, y, 0.3, 0.5],
 {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10},
 PlotPoints -> 100
 ]
```

[image: Density plot]

Answer (score 2):

```
myBlock = ImplicitRegion[RegionMember[Cuboid[], {x, y, z}], {x, y, z}];

myHole[xcenter_, ycenter_, radius_, depth_] := 
ImplicitRegion[
RegionMember[
Cylinder[{{xcenter, ycenter, 1.05}, {xcenter, ycenter, 1 - depth}}, radius], 
{x, y, z}], {x, y, z}];

RegionPlot3D[
RegionDifference[myBlock,
   RegionUnion[
   Table[myHole[x, y, .06, .3], {x, .2, .8, .2}, {y, .2, .8, .2}]]],
PlotPoints -> 100]
```

[image]

If you want to have a single iteration variable, use `Mod` and `Floor` this way:

```
RegionPlot3D[
RegionDifference[myBlock,
  RegionUnion[
 Table[myHole[.25 (Mod[i, 3]+1), .25 (Mod[Floor[i/3], 3]+1), .06, .3], 
 {i, 0, 8}]]],
 PlotPoints -> 100,
 Boxed->False]
```